# Apply screen transition direction to an element card inside an expansion panel and screen kivy/kivymd

Tags: python, kivy, attributeerror, kivymd

I am a new programmer, working on a `Kivy` app and I need to use `screens (screen manager)`, the issue is that I am using element cards as but buttons, and it is supposed that when using `on_release` it will change the screen, however if I include `root.manager.transition.direction = "left"`  I get the error  `AttributeError: 'MyContentComunes' object has no attribute 'screen'`. I don't know if anyone could help me with this.

**Here is a piece of code.**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.expansionpanel import MDExpansionPanel, MDExpansionPanelTwoLine
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.color_definitions import colors
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen

KV = '''

WindowManager:

    id: screen_manager

    PrincipalWindow:

    LenghtWindow:

<PrincipalWindow>:

    name: "principal"

    BoxLayout:

        MDToolbar:

            title: "Conversor"

            pos_hint: {"top": 1}

    ScrollView:

        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}   #Ubicación

        size_hint: 0.90, 0.75

        GridLayout:

            halign: 'center'

            cols: 1

            adaptive_height: True

            id: box

<LenghtWindow>:

    name: "Lenght"

    md_bg_color: 0.34,0.024,0.292,1

    MDBoxLayout:

        orientation: "vertical"

        MDToolbar:

            title: "Conversor"

            pos_hint: {"top": 1} 


        Button:

            text: "Back"

            font_size: 32

            on_release: 

                app.root.current = "principal"

                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"


<MyContentComunes>:

    orientation: 'vertical'

    padding: dp(10)

    spacing: dp(10)

    size_hint_y: None

    height: self.minimum_height

    ElementCard:                     

        image:"1490820814-13_82405.png"

        text:"Longitud"

        id:longitud

        on_release: 

            app.root.current = "Lenght"

            root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

<ElementCard@MDCard>:

    md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color

    padding: dp(15)

    spacing: dp(15)

    size_hint: 1, None

    ripple_behavior: True

    # on_release: print("worked")   
             
    image:''

    text:""

    items_count:""

    subtext:''

    orientation: "vertical"

    Image:

        source:root.image

        halign:"center"

        padding: dp (4)

        spacing: dp(4)

    MDBoxLayout:

        orientation: "vertical"

        MDLabel:

            halign:"center"

            text:root.text 

        MDLabel:

            halign:"center"

            font_style:"Caption"
            
            text:root.subtext 

'''

Window.size = 324, 720

class Conversor(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Blue"
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.list_items = []  # Dictionary where the items are stored
        self.category_list1 = ['Comunes']

    def on_start(self):
        for category in self.category_list1:
            self.root.get_screen('principal').ids.box.add_widget(
                MDExpansionPanel(
                    icon="3.png",
                    content=MyContentComunes(),
                    panel_cls=MDExpansionPanelTwoLine(
                        text=category,
                        secondary_text="Ver las unidades"
                    )
                )
            )


class MyContentComunes(BoxLayout):

    pass


class PrincipalWindow(Screen):

    pass

class LenghtWindow(Screen):

    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):

    pass


Conversor().run()
```

The element card is inside an expansion panel, which is also inside a screen.

Comment: When you ask questions, take care of the [lminimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) . Don't worry. I also was like you when I was a beginner to stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `Screen` to class `MyContentComunes`.

```
class MyContentComunes(BoxLayout, Screen):
    pass
```

And I recommend you to organize your code like this. It will make your work more eaisier.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivymd.app import MDApp
# import libraries ...

KV = '''
# Your KV File
'''

Window.size = 324, 720

class MyContentComunes(BoxLayout, Screen):
    pass


class PrincipalWindow(Screen):
    pass


class LenghtWindow(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class Conversor(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Blue"
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # Code
        .
        .
        .

    def on_start(self):
        # Code
        .
        .
        .


Conversor().run()
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your fast respond. I tried the solution you gave me, but it didn't worked, however I made the code work using:             app.root.get_screen('principal').manager.transition.direction = "left". Thank you for your help I really appreciate it and I will organize my code as you recommend

Comment: Okay! Well done.